# jQuery Supersized Plugin: Placing the thumbnails in a different location

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, supersized

Is it possible to place the thumbnails that Supersized generates in a different location on the page?

I can see that `api.options.slides` would give me the slides and thumb paths. Can I somehow use this to recreate the thumbnails somewhere else on the page?

I'd like to put the thumbnails on the left sidebar for example.

[Sample Page](http://www.concordbuilders.com.php53-8.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/project/sample-project-20/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I implemented it:

```
if ( $("#supersized").length ) {
    $('.container').append('<ul class="cloned-thumbs"></ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < api.options.slides.length; i++) {
        $('.cloned-thumbs').append('<li><img onclick="javascript: api.goTo(' + (i+1) +')" src="' + api.options.slides[i].thumb + '"></li>');
    }
}
```